# Goal Seek implementation in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to implement the Excel goal seek function in groovy

I have already made it work to give the correct result but I am sure that my code can be improved in terms of performance and accuracy. Mostly the way I am trying to find the correct adjustment to solve the goal seek.
A hardcoded increase / decrees don't seem the best way to go, but I am not sure how to calculate more efficient.

On this var **thisVarToBeZero**
i have the sum of the attribute of all Elements which I want to be Zero by changing the Adjustment in the calculation

```
   mapWithElements={
        element1:{
        "value2":130.24,
        "value1":33700,
        "value3":50.5,
        "result":0.0},

        element2:{
            "value1":23489,
            "value2":108.24,
            "value3":62.78,
            "result":0.0},

        element3={
               "value1":140,
               "value2":57.22,
               "value3":46.65,
               "result":0.0}            
  }  

   thisVarToBeZero =  mapWithElements.each(){ key,value->
        value["result"]=value1*(((value2*adjusment)+value2)-value3)
    }.each {it->
        it.value=it.value["result"]
    }.collect() {it->it.value}.sum()


/* at this point i have the sum of the result of all elements */

def adjustment=0.0
def exit= false
def count=0

while(!exit){

    if(thisVarToBeZero> 0){

        if(thisVarToBeZero<=2000){       // this if is a threshold in case the equation can't be zero

            exit=true
        }

        adjusment-=0.00001              //  decreese the adjusment

    }else if(thisVarToBeZero< 0){

        if(thisVarToBeZero>=-2000){       // this if is a threshold in case the equation can't be zero

            exit=true
        }

        adjusment+=0.00001              // increese the adjusment

    }else{

        exit=true
    }

    if(count>=1000000){                     // Safety variable to don't go to infinity loop
        return "Solution not found"
    }
    count++
}
return adjusment
```

Comment: From what i found a possible solution could be with [newton's method](https://www.google.com/search?q=newton%27s+method&oq=newton%27s+method+&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l3j69i61j69i60.4354j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but i can't figure it out how to implement it on this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone interested on the topic.
Actually this variant of the problem can be very easily solved with Linear interpolation. (I found this useful https://www.johndcook.com/interpolator.html)

the modification can be the following.

instead, of while loop:

```
def fx(x){

    def guessAdjustment =  mapWithElements.values().sum{ 
         it.value1 * ( ( ( it.value2 * adjustment ) + it.value2 ) - it.value3 ) 
         }
    return guessAdjustment
}

def x1=0.01
def x2=-0.01
def y1=fx(x1)
def y2=fx(x2)
def y3=0

def finalAdjustment = ((y2-y3)*x1 + (y3-y1)*x2) / (y2-y1)

return finalAdjustment
```

Answer (score 0):

This horrible assembly

```
   thisVarToBeZero =  mapWithElements.each(){ key,value->
        value["result"]=value1*(((value2*adjusment)+value2)-value3)
    }.each {it->
        it.value=it.value["result"]
    }.collect() {it->it.value}.sum()
```

can be rewritten as:

```
thisVarToBeZero = mapWithElements.values().sum{ 
  it.value1 * ( ( ( it.value2 * adjustment ) + it.value2 ) - it.value3 ) 
}
```